# server error when reading in an xml file

Tags: asp.net

I have some xml files which contain the source data for populating dropdown lists in my pages. These dropdowns are re-populated based on selected items from other dropdwons. I am getting a server error

> Could not find a part of the path
>   X:\ASP.Net\CommodDisplay\DataFiles\dataXML.xml'.

Even though this is a valid path.

Here is the code im using to call it;

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        'Load XML from the file into XmlDocument object
        doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DataFiles/dataXML.xml"))

        Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement

        'Select all nodes with the tag Book
        Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("futures")
        For Each node As XmlNode In nodeList
            ddlMainsub1.Items.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("product").InnerText)
        Next
```

I also tried it just using Server.MapPath and I get the same error. These files are in a networked drive. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asp.net service is running under a different user account then your own. You should be sure the service account has access to the path:

```
X:\ASP.Net\CommodDisplay\DataFiles\dataXML.xml
```

If part of the path is a network mapping it is possible that it is mapped for you but not for the service account running your website. Put all files local and try if that helps.